# How to make geocodeAddressString more sensitive to ALL district names

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.3

```
    [Geocode geocodeAddressString:someSearchString completionHandler: ^(NSArray * placemarks, NSError *error)
     {
         [self ParseDistrict:placemarks];
         [ThreadClass CommitWithDoMOCUpdate];
         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:notifyFinishDownloadingData object:self];
     }];
```

There is a district named Kemayoran. However I got to fed someSearchString kemayora to get kemayoran show up.

The same way I have to insert tebet to get Tebet showing up.

I already use regions and concentrate on regions nearby me. Still doesn't work.

Comment: were you able to find anything?

Comment: No Not at all. Go back to google.